# VS2010 : Discrepancy in Debug and Release Configurations when adding references

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, com

I have a VB.Net project which is referring to a 3rd party DLL. When I add a reference to it, VS2010 generates an Interop. I am struggling with the Debug and Release configurations. I have them setup for Any Platform (Any CPU). Here is a gist of what happens;

*Scenario 1*
- Select Debug mode as Active
- Add the reference to the DLL (I am doing it through Browse, and not through the COM tab)
- Save the Configuration. I note that in the references tab there is a reference to only the Debug folder Interop; but when I examine the folders, the interop is copied to both Debug and Release folders and the configuration is correctly pointing to respective InterOps
- Start debugging with Debug configuration as Active. The Program fails at CreateObject call (for a class in the referenced DLL) with error "Cannot create ActiveX component"
- Change the Active mode to Release
- Start debugging with Release configuration as Active. The Program runs fine
- Execute the Release folder's exe from command prompt and I get the error "Cannot create ActiveX component" again

*Scenario 2*
- Select Release mode as Active
- Add the reference to the DLL (I am doing it through Browse, and not through the COM tab)
- Save the Configuration. I note that in the references tab there is a reference to only the Release folder Interop; but when I examine the folders, the interop is copied to both Debug and Release folders and the configuration is correctly pointing to respective InterOps
- Start debugging with Release configuration as Active. The Program fails at CreateObject call (for a class in the referenced DLL) with error "Cannot create ActiveX component"
- Change the Active mode to Debug
- Start debugging with Debug configuration as Active. The Program runs fine
- Execute the Debug folder's exe from command prompt and I get the error "Cannot create ActiveX component" again

This is driving me nuts. The Exe doesn't run from either folder. I have tried all possible permutations and as you can see both the scenarios described above are mirror images of each other; determined by what was the active configuration at the time of adding the reference.

Any help would be very much appreciated!!

Comment: Removed the reference, changed the configuration to x86. Then cleaned the solution and added the reference back (with Release mode active) and rebuilt the solution. Same issue (works in Debug, not in Release). Anything else I can/should do?

Comment: I am unable to put a screenshot here. When I changed the Project -> Properties -> Compile Options -> Configuration (Active Debug) Platform (x86); it changed the same in the Target settings in Advanced Compile Options as well. There is no change in behavior.